# JQuery find element that has specific value without loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out if there is a way (without using any loops like each etc..) to look up element that has specific value, something like

```
var myElment = $('.container');
var child = $('.container-child');
myElement.find(child /* That has value of test */);
```

value is related to `.val()` of child element, so text inside it.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by value? The class? The attributes? Or is it an input-field?

Comment: What do you mean by specific value. Is that a form element?

Comment: @Abaddon666 Updated my question.

Comment: @Zealander Updated the question

Comment: `var child = $('.container-child[value=YOUR_VALUE]');`

Comment: `$('.container .container-child:contains("test")')`

Comment: Some sample html would be helpful.

Comment: As an aside for deeper understanding, `.find()` is also going to be iterating over elements under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [Attribute Equals Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) which is `[attr=value]`.

So, to do that, just use

```
$(".container .container-child[value='test']")
```